# In this jQuery slide, calling a function from inside another function causes it to run multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fw2J5/) very simple slider that I took (with some improvements) from [this](http://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl) codepen I want to `fadeOut` the `<p>` elements inside the `li` elements after the `.animate` starts and when the transition ends I want to `.fadeIn` the `<p>` elements again. Now, I put a `.fadeToggle` that calls the function `moveLeft` when it ends:

```
function showHideTitle() {
    $('#slider ul li p').fadeToggle('500', function(){
        moveLeft();
    })
};
```

And then, when the `.animate` ends the `.fadeToggle` is called again revealing the `<p>` element.

```
function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: +slideWidth
    }, 600, function () {

        $('#slider ul li p').fadeToggle('500');

        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
}
```

Now, **the problem** is that in the example if you press the left button you will see how the `<p>` elements fades out but, the function `moveLeft` runs until it reach the end of the `<ul>`. In other words if I call the function `moveleft` directly it works, but if I call it from inside another function it runs multiple times.

What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with your selector, not the function.

`'#slider ul li p'` applies to 4 elements, so the function gets called 4 times, once per element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It was the animation queue building up, not the selector. But your answer took me to another post where a similar problem was solved using `.stop` In that way the `.animation` only runs in the first element that finds.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was simpler than I expected it was just a animation queue building up. A `.stop()` was enough to make it work.

```
function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').stop().animate({
        left: -slideWidth
    }, 600, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
}
```